# Can I have 1 business acct and 2 personal accts in a Paypal Express Checkout Parallel Payments transaction?

Tags: paypal

To elaborate on the question further, the 1 business account is the website administrator who is the host merchant, while the other 2 personal accounts belong to the buyer and another seller.

Does Express Checkout Parallel Payments require app approval from Paypal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need approval from PayPal:

More information [here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/).

Read where it says about "Reviewing applications with Adaptive API calls"

Comment: Thanks, but the main question hasn't been answered - Can I have 1 business acct and 2 personal accts in a Paypal Express Checkout Parallel Payments transaction?

Comment: I guess a simple test in sandbox will answer your question. I would say yes, but maybe payments would be marked as pending.